# How to know when a polynomial belongs to a certain ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals, groebner-basis

I am trying to compute manually a Gröbner basis for $I=\langle f=x_3-x_1^5,g=x_2-x_1^3\rangle$ with the lexicographic order. After the third iteration I get,
$$h_1=x_1^2x_2-x_3$$
$$h_2=x_1x_3-x_2^2$$
$$h_3=x_1x_2^3-x_3^2$$
$$h_4=x_3(x_1^4-x_2^3)$$
$$h_5=x_3^3-x_2^5$$
macaulay2 says that the basis should be $\{g,h_1,h_2,h_3,h_5\}$, so my question is, how can I prove that $h_4\in\langle g,h_1,h_2,h_3,h_5\rangle$ if the division algorithm doesn't work? This would be also usefull to prove that all the $S$-polynomials on the next iteration are 0.

Comment: I obtain $x_2h_2-x_1^3x_3g=x_3x_1^4-x_2^3\in I$. Is there typo in $h_4$ ?

Comment: You can change the order with macaulay2, I changed it to lex

Comment: I think you've made an error.  Sage says that $h_4$ is not in your ideal $I$.  (This agrees with your observation that dividing $h_4$ by $\{g,h_1,h_2,h_3,h_5\}$ leaves a nonzero remainder.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error computing $h_4$,
$$h_4=S(f,h_3)=x_1^4x_3^2-x_2^3x_3$$
after that I used the division algorithm with $h_2$ and I get on the first iteration that,
$$x_3(x_1^3x_3h_2-x_2^2g)=h_4$$
so it is,
$$h_4\equiv 0\mod I$$